# Change bootstrap css file, but not working

Tags: html, css

I test the AVS 7.0(adultvideoscript) theme, editing  `.btn`(in bootstrap.css), changed the [`margin-bottom`] from `0` to `4px`, but not work in frontend, someone can help me?

I think it may edit something in mysql, but I dont know which files need to edit, one more thing, sql is not new created, it has some data I created before.

```
btn: margin-bottom: 0; to margin-bottom: 4px
```

Comment: Please provide minimal working code

Answer (score -1):

Add Parent Class (Before Btn Class) Like below Css

> .add_parent_class_here .btn { margin-bottom: 4px; }